# C++/Linux: how do you write a thread-safe library that uses sockets?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, fork

I want to write a library in C++ under Linux that will help an application to use a certain protocol (FastCGI, actually). The library will listen to a socket (either TCP or Unix), receive requests, forward them to user code, and send responses generated by said user code.

There will be many connections on the socket and each connection will carry many requests (possibly simultaneously - there is an interleaving mechanism). The user code (which uses the library) will most likely be multithreaded in order to process several requests in parallel.

I'd like my library to be robust and make as little assumptions/requirements about the user code as possible, including the type of multithreading used. As I understand, the `clone()` function in Linux can fork a process in dozens of different manners - with or without shared memory, shared file handles, etc. The decision of HOW to implement multithreading should be left to the user.

And this confuses me, because the library code can suddenly find itself `fork()`'ed, and multiple copies of the code can be suddenly reading from the same socket and handling the same request. Even worse - the parent process might terminate, leaving only child processes, which in turn spawn more child processes, perhaps even in different process namespaces - it's a mess.

What are the Linux facilities that help to coordinate all the copies of the same code which need to access the same external resource (a socket)? What is the standard way of implementing such thread-safe libraries? Must I choose a threading model myself and impose that upon the consumers of my library?

Comment: We're talking about threads, `fork` *and* `clone` all in one breath... that's a tall order.

Comment: @KerrekSB: as I said - I'd like this choice (threads/fork/clone) to reside with the users of my library, and the library should be able to handle however it is used... if it's possible, of course. :P I also read somewhere that `fork()` is actually `clone()` with a specific set of flags.

Comment: @KerrekSB: P.S. I'm quite familiar with Windows, but I haven't yet written anything on Linux, which probably shows. I'm trying to wrap my brain around the Linux way of doing things.

Comment: For what it's worth, on Linux I'd go with edge-triggered `epoll` on non-blocking file descriptors; if you register the epoll events as "one-shot", then this is guaranteed to be sane even when polled concurrently (i.e. precisely one thread handles the event).

Comment: Forget about `clone`, *especially* if you know nothing about it. Forget about it *now*. Second, `fork` makes *processes*, not threads, so it's probably completely irrelevant to the present situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB - OK, if you say so... I just remember that on Linux it's quite common to have a "master" process and "worker" processes (like in Apache), so I thought that it's quite likely that people will want to implement parallel processing that way.

Comment: But that's a really, really deep decision you need to make way earlier in your design process. It's like deciding whether you rather have children or become a travel writer in Mali when you turn 34. Processes and threads are very, very different things as far as your program design is concerned. If you're unsure about *that*, post that as a separate question, and then come back with a *specific* question about either IPC with processes, or about IO in a multithreaded program.

Comment: @KerrekSB - would you be willing to chat about this? I really want to talk to someone more experienced.

Comment: You can always try the C++ Lounge chat room here on SO for quality feedback...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use directly `clone` (reserve `clone` to *implementors* of threading libraries like `pthread`). Don't use a lot of `fork`-s (probably none). Go using `pthread`-s.

You could look at the design of the [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) library. It is small, implements HTTP server protocol, so is quite similar to your goals.

<sup>`libonion` gives the users various modes for creating or not threads for requests.</sup>

You could have options similar to `libonion`-s about creating, or not, a new thread for each FastCGI request.

You might perhaps want to use some event looping library like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) (around a [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html)-ing loop).

And read good books, notably [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), and some [tutorial on *Pthread*-s](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) before starting coding.

Also, study the source code of several *free software libraries* similar to your goals.

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of seemingly going off at a tangent I'd recommend implementing fastcgi on a **single thread per processor** basis.

Reasons:

1. More robust.
2. Avoids context-switching overhead associated with multi-threading and protects you from issues like concurrency deadlocks.
3. Avoids process fork() costs (although quite light it all adds up)
   and protects you from dealing with potential child zombie processes amongst other headaches.

This would leave you with the choice of implementing the fastcgi interface using :

1. **Non-blocking synchronous I/O** ([Reactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) design pattern): block until a read or write request comes in, pass request to the
   appropriate handler and then block until the next request comes in.
2. **Asynchronous I/O** ([Proactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proactor_pattern) design pattern): pass read and write requests to the operating system where the O/S supports I/O
   completion events. On Windows that would be [IO completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
   and on Linux something like [epoll()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll).

Comment: It probably is a good idea if every FastCGI request can be answered quite quickly (less than 100 milliseconds). If the OP also wants to handle some rare, but costly -i.e. slow responding FastCGI requests- e.g. requiring more than a second of CPU time, or needing to make many complex and costly database queries, it might be less obvious....

Comment: That's indeed a tangent. In case I wasn't clear, I don't want to force anything from the consumers of the library. If they want to spawn a single thread per processor - that's fine. If they want to spawn 100 worker processes - that's also fine. If they want to spawn 5 processes of 20 threads each, alternating the usage based on moon phases - that's also fine. Can it be done at all?

Comment: What I mean is - I don't want my library to spawn anything AT ALL. The consumer should be responsible for that. The consumer should implement the main application loop. My library should just tag along happily and spit out a request or two when asked for it.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch - this is more true for the single-threaded Reactor implementation. Provided the operating system has robust async I/O, the Proactor pattern pattern is very scalable. Having the core of the event/io dispatching on a single thread does not prevent handling  potential long-running operations on a separate thread.

Comment: @Vilx - so you want to write a shared library which provides facilities for dealing with fastcgi requests but the caller is responsible for dealing with I/O events? Or am I minsunderstanding?

Comment: @Anthill - the library will abstract away everything to do with communication with the webserver. That includes socket IO, protocol processing, etc. The caller is responsible for deciding on everything else - including how many threads/processes there will be that will handle these requests. Maybe it's impossible, I don't know.